# select all xml child nodes that start with a string or another string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmldocument

I am using C# .

I was given an xml node from out client with child nodes as follows :

```
<PriceID>32</PriceID>
<Store_1> 344</Store_1>
      <Store_32> 343 </Store_32>
       <SS> 54</SS>
```

I would like to select all nodes that start with **Store** & **SS**

Is there a way I can do it ?

I know there is a way to select nodes which start with Store :

```
   list = el.SelectNodes(@"node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store')]");
```

I would like to select all nodes that start with "Store" & "SS" .

Please let me know.

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument? Can you use LINQ to XML instead? I'd personally find that simpler... `var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Store") || x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("SS"));`

Comment: I would prefer using xmldocument as we use it heavily & it will be consistent with rest of our code.

Comment: I suspect that just means that a *lot* of your code could be simplified :) The fact that `XmlDocument` doesn't have a hugely clean way of iterating over all elements is a pain :(

Comment: Yes ! You are actually right :-) .

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ to XML, it's simple:

```
var results = doc.Descendants()
                 .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Store") || 
                             x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("SS"));
```

With `XmlDocument` it's harder because there's no direct equivalent of `Descendants()` or `DescendantsAndSelf`. You could write your own extension method:

```
// I'm assuming we don't mind too much about the ordering...
public static IEnumerable<XmlElement> DescendantsAndSelf(this XmlElement node)
{
    return new[] { node }.Concat(node.ChildNodes
                                     .OfType<XmlElement>()
                                     .SelectMany(x => x.DescendantsAndSelf()));
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var results = doc.DocumentElement.DescendantsAndSelf()
                 .Where(x => x.LocalName.StartsWith("Store") || 
                             x.LocalName.StartsWith("SS"));
```

Comment: Hi Jon ! Thank you for the response. While writing the above extension method , I am getting a compile time error saysing system.xml.xmlelement does not contain a defintion for descendants

Comment: @PowerCoder: Fixed now - try again.